# JSON subsetting unique dates in R

Tags: json, r

I am having difficulty subsetting JSON data. I am fairly new to R understand the basics of subsetting.

```
    library(jsonlite)
    library(curl)

    url1="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=RCS&outputsize=full&apikey=DEMO"

    StockData2<- fromJSON(url1,flatten = TRUE)
```

Data looks like this coming in (2 days worth out of 4394 days).  The trouble I am having is each date is unique and I can't figure out how to pull just the date and one of its subsetted prices out.

```
> str(StockData)
List of 2
 $ Meta Data          :List of 5
  ..$ 1. Information   : chr "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events"
  ..$ 2. Symbol        : chr "RCS"
  ..$ 3. Last Refreshed: chr "2017-06-20 10:27:00"
  ..$ 4. Output Size   : chr "Full size"
  ..$ 5. Time Zone     : chr "US/Eastern"
 $ Time Series (Daily):List of 4394
  ..$ 2017-06-20 10:27:00:List of 8
  .. ..$ 1. open             : chr "10.1100"
  .. ..$ 2. high             : chr "10.1600"
  .. ..$ 3. low              : chr "10.0400"
  .. ..$ 4. close            : chr "10.1100"
  .. ..$ 5. adjusted close   : chr "10.1100"
  .. ..$ 6. volume           : chr "17776"
  .. ..$ 7. dividend amount  : chr "0.00"
  .. ..$ 8. split coefficient: chr "1.0000"
  ..$ 2017-06-19         :List of 8
  .. ..$ 1. open             : chr "9.9200"
  .. ..$ 2. high             : chr "10.1200"
  .. ..$ 3. low              : chr "9.9200"
  .. ..$ 4. close            : chr "10.0800"
  .. ..$ 5. adjusted close   : chr "10.0800"
  .. ..$ 6. volume           : chr "160599"
  .. ..$ 7. dividend amount  : chr "0.00"
  .. ..$ 8. split coefficient: chr "1.0000"

Daily<-StockData$`Time Series (Daily)`
```

Will produce a large list of 4394 elements.  **How do I get just "dates" and "adjusted close" out of this list?**

Comment: Note: it seems you need a valid API key for this to work as posted/

Comment: Sorry.  This will work.  line.library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
url1="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"
StockData2<- fromJSON(url1,flatten = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Now I can get the data I have a full solution. My earlier answer, which used `as.data.frame`, failed on the real data (but worked on my test) because of the way that `as.data.frame` tried to get the column names from the expression passed in. For some rare combination of data names and types that your data triggered, `as.data.frame` ended up trying to set the wrong number of column names. Using `data.frame` instead, or adding the `optional=FALSE` argument to `as.data.frame` fixes this.

So the solution is:

```
result = setNames(
   data.frame(
     sapply(
       StockData2[["Time Series (Daily)"]],
         function(x){
           x[["5. adjusted close"]]
            })),
   c("adjusted close"))
```

giving:

```
> head(result)
           adjusted close
2017-06-21        70.2700
2017-06-20        69.9100
2017-06-19        70.8700
2017-06-16        70.0000
2017-06-15        69.9000
2017-06-14        70.2700
```

If you are interested in what caused the fail, read on...

Set up two very similar lists:

```
> Xnum = list(list(x=1),list(x=2))
> Xchar = list(list(x="1"),list(x="2"))
```

Convert `x` bits to a data frame. For the numbers, it works, but as you see the column name is a bit long, but no problem:

```
> as.data.frame(sapply(Xnum,function(f){f$x}))
  sapply(Xnum, function(f) {     f$x })
1                                     1
2                                     2
```

But for the character one, it gets in a real mess:

```
> as.data.frame(sapply(Xchar,function(f){f$x}))
Error in as.data.frame.vector(x, ..., nm = nm) : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

because it ends up splitting the `sapply(Xchar,function(f){f$x})` expression into three parts. I don't know why the numeric version doesn't fall foul to this.

Comment: Thank you!  I am having trouble executing the setNames line.library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
url1="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"
StockData2<- fromJSON(url1,flatten = TRUE)

Comment: Thank you!  I am having trouble executing the setNames line.   'setNames(as.data.frame(sapply(StockData2[["Time Series (Daily)"]],function(x){x[["5. adjusted close"]]})),c("adjusted close"))' results in **Error in as.data.frame.vector(x, ..., nm = nm) : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]**  I am sorry...having trouble getting this formatted too.

Comment: I am certain the parenthesis are paired correctly.  I have really tried to get this to work.  Any further pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tracked this down to a really annoying problem in R when it tries to get names from an object in order to make a data frame. If you do it in two steps: foo = sapply(...); result = setNames(foo,.....)` it is likely to work.